# Firebase Log in on debug application SHA Fingerprint

Tags: android, firebase, debugging, fingerprint, sha

What is the best way to enable firebase login in the debug version of my android app? Should I use the same signing Config used for generating the apk for the play store and get the sha fingerprint that way, or is there an easier solution for debug android apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the SHA-1 from your debug key.  You can add multiple SHA-1 for each of your build environments in the Firebase console, and they will all work at the same time.  No need to force all debug builds to use a release signing key.

Comment: In our case, we have different firebase projects and using the same bundle name... having different build environments would address one side of the fence, what about firebase? Any thoughts on this?